# How to treat folders as one while in using flow_from_directory while actually copying them .?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have four classes in my dataset ( A,B,C,D)
Instead of using a flat multiclass classifier , I'm trying to use multiple binary classifiers .
Example:

Firstly - A vs B

Then ( A&B vs C )

Then ( A&B&C vs D )

How to do it via the use of flow_from_directory without actually combining the contents of the folder into the new folders each time .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first case you can specify the attribute `classes` from [flow_from_directory](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory)

```
generator.flow_from_directory('./train', classes=['A', 'B'])
```

For the other cases check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52392763/844372

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for this ! But actually I wanted to know how to consider A&B as one class ,without actually copying the images of A & B into one .

Comment: Try to merge the generators: [https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8130#issuecomment-336855177](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8130#issuecomment-336855177)

Comment: Seems to be helpful ! Thanks @Daniel